# Help me clean some ugly XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm getting this XML from a service that I need to deal with.  I'm not much on XML Schema or Namespace fu, but to me it looks a mess.  Can someone take a look at it and tell me how to make it nicer?

http://gist.github.com/325952

I know that the namespace definitions can be declared in the first line, and not on **every** line.  Is there anything else that can be cleaned up?

Comment: I believe the URI for the namespace is supposed to be a valid RFC 3986 URI, or at least if they are going to use the "http" prefix. And this is not.  Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: There's no reason why it HAS to be, it's just common practice - but it does follow that if you're going to include a URI it should be valid.

Edit: In fact, I thought someone should point out - an XML namespace is just a string. It is 'tradition' to use a URI for this, but it is equally valid to use anything else. No lookup of the URI ever occurs at any point.

Comment: @Daniel I-S I think you probably meant to say "it's a tradition to use a URL". It does have to be a URI, but yes, a URI does not need a protocol qualifier, etc., hence a plain string works. URNs are also used in some places I've worked.

Comment: StackOverflow questions need to be complete enough to be answerable **without external links**. Including a link for additional content is fine, but a question needs to have enough content quoted to still be useful to others if the link were to break.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260565/how-strict-should-we-be-when-enforcing-the-no-external-sites-or-the-no-code for discussion on the topic; I think this falls into the "potentially useful if it had the code" category, so to be a good (rule-compliant) question, a subset of the XML in question sufficient to demonstrate its problems needs to be added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say: leave the first two elements with the xsd prefix: it only occurs in the two outermost elements. In addition, declare `xmlns="http://com/acmephone/ovm/cas/types"` at the root and remove the `typ:` prefix from everything.

*Edit:* Actually change the xsd prefix to some other prefix; it does not matter much, but it seems to cause only confusion to use a prefix that is normally bound to the XML schema namespace.

Comment: +1 I tried the same thing, but as I wanted to explain it I get stuck in W3C specs

Comment: Well, should be easy enough to get started. Remove all xmlns:typ="" attributes; Then search and replace typ: with the empty string, finally put the declaration in my answer at the root.